# How to keep printing a different number every second until user enters stop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to print a number EACH second (slow) in a while loop. Once they enter "stop", the loop should break and get the number they entered "stop" on. Here is my code.

```
def main():
    ask = input('Enter stop if you want to break: ')
    while True:
    if ask == 'go':
        random_target = random.randint(100,999)
        print(random_target)
    elif ask == 'stop':
        break
```

Comment: Why isn't `input` inside your `while` loop? Also your indentation is off.

Comment: You can use ```time.sleep(1)``` in order to wait a second.

Answer (score -1):

Using `time.sleep(1)` would work. So, in your code,

```
import time
def main():
    time.sleep(1)#Replace 1 with time in seconds for which you want to slow down
    ask = input('Enter stop if you want to break: ')
    while True:
    if ask == 'go':
        random_target = random.randint(100,999)
        print(random_target)
    elif ask == 'stop':
        break
```

Reference:https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep

> Suspend execution of the calling thread for the given number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time.